# How do I convert org.json.simple.jsonobject to java object

Tags: java, json, spring, hibernate

Is it possible to convert org.json.simple.jsonobject to java object

Comment: was that a question or an answer ?
if yes, then the answer would be yes it's possible using ObjectMapper.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to use jackson's objectMapper for this

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper=new ObjectMapper();
ClassName object=objectMapper.readValue(json.toString(),ClassName.class);
```

To use GSON

```
Gson g = new Gson();
ClassName object=g.fromJSON(json.toString(),ClassName.class);
```

Comment: JSONObject *is* a Java object.  I'm confused.  Do you mean binding JSON to a POJO of your own devising?  The Jackson docs should make that clear.

Comment: I don't use jackson, since my JSON is large and complex structured

Comment: do you use gson?

Comment: i would recommend you to use either of them

Comment: refer:https://blog.takipi.com/the-ultimate-json-library-json-simple-vs-gson-vs-jackson-vs-json/

Comment: ufile.io/09ly2   ca

Comment: can you do for the above?

Answer (score 0):

Of course it is possibile. In the most obvious case you can set each property of the target object with the corresponding value in the json object. More than *conversion*, I would call this object *creation*.

Comment: No, I cant make a Model because my JSON is large and complex structured

Comment: You have defined the target class, no? So, you can also define a creation method I think. Otherwise you should use some library as suggested in the other answer by Gupta.